# Why did I fail this "Low Quality Posts" review audit?

Tags: support, review-audits, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits

I was going through the "Low Quality Posts" review queue and I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53556539/hkstatisticscollectionquery-not-returning-newest-data). It's a short question, so I'll include it here:

> I am using a `HKStatisticsCollectionQuery` to receive steps data from Healthkit. It works perfectly fine until some point where my app is not returning new health data anymore. It starts to work again as soon as I re-install the app. Does anybody have a clue why this happens?

I chose to vote-to-close this as off-topic with the "why isn't this code working" option (I also considered "too broad").

As is obvious from the title of my question here, I failed the audit. I could see that the question I'd acted on had 6 upvotes and no close votes at all.

Should I have failed this audit? Obviously, I don't think so, but I've had a similar experience before and I'm now on a 2-day ban (I think - it could be more).

Comment: Looks like another bad question pick for an audit.

Comment: Audits are chosen automatically. Since this question has accrued down-votes and close-votes since you got is as an audit, it will be removed from the audit-pool and no longer be an issue.

Comment: Lifted the ban in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and ban lift. For future reference, is this the correct way to get this sorted?

Comment: Yes, @Kirk. Thanks for bringing it up; other folks here have ensured this question won't get used as an audit again, and BoltClock has ensured your review-ban won't stick... Meanwhile, there's something a bit fishy about this question, gonna dig into it further.

Comment: @yivi Wait, so you're telling me that if I create a whole bunch of different accounts, then post "How is babby formed?" from one of them and upvote it from all the rest, I can lay a land mine in the audit system?

Comment: @charles I’m not telling you anything. But audits are chosen automatically, and I guess you could trick the system; but you would have to be lucky to accomplish it; since not all universally upvoted questions are chosen as audits; and the fact that you could use sock puppet accounts to upvote a question doesn’t mean the would not receive downvotes or close votes from real users; thus disqualifying them from the audit pool.

Comment: @yivi I dunno, it'd probably be possible to sneak a question past the radar by posting the question at 3 AM in an obscure tag like `[filenet-bpf]` with a reasonable-enough-looking title...

Answer (score 6):

This particular case was sorted out, but more generally, from my experience (11000+ VLQ reviews), questions in VLQ are audits 99% of the time.

So next time check the actual question status & votes by using the "link" link if you see a question in the VLQ.

Comment: Where the 1% was before triage, where auto low quality flags go to the VLQ queue.

Comment: 99% That's not my experience at all... I don't keep statistics, but the impression is that there aren't more VLQ audits than in other queues...

Comment: Personally, I _never_ saw a question that wasn't an audit. I just didn't want to state that 100% of the questions of the VLQ were audits. People just don't flag them as is, but rather as "too broad", etc..

Comment: So you're saying that the audit system is terrible and the solution to that is to game it. Or maybe SO should actually make it better instead of wasting the time of people willing to spend time cleaning up garbage on this site.

Comment: that's one practical answer. I can't change SO, I'm adapting to it. There's no gamification here. The system is trying to bust the roboreviewers too, so maybe it's gaming us. And for which privileges would we game the system? none (after 11000 reviews I've got nothing to gain cheating)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: I can only be bothered with close and reopen now.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Sadly, people flag questions as VLQ all the time (it's not useful, they should *always* be flagging them for a different reason, but they do it anyway), but 0% of those questions go tot he LQP queue, they go to Triage.  (They used to go to LQP before Triage existed.)

Comment: @Servy okay! thanks Triage for me will you ? and thanks for the info